# VSCode does not run pytest properly from virtual environment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytest

I just discovered that vscode is able to run pytest directly out of the editor. That's pretty awesome - if it would work.

Currently I'm working on a project within a virtual environment, which is properly configured in vscode (and activated). pytest is installed in the virtual environment and activated as well, the tests I wrote are discovered as expected. But whenever I run a test, it says, that it does not find the module I'm currently working on and a `ModuleNotFoundError` is raised.

I have installed this module with `pip install -e .`. Running the same tests on a normal terminal console outside vscode works like expected.

It does not make a difference if pytest is enabled for the workspache only and/or for the user.

Sample code:

```py
def test_something():
   from mymodule.config import Config
   ...
```

Output:

```
E       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mymodule'
```

Pip sample output:

```
mymodule               0.1.0     /path/to/mymodule
```

Stange is also, that vscode runs the correct pytest script (it is not installed globally, only in this environment) with all installed plugins (i.e. pytest-datafiles).

Any ideas why?

Regards, Thomas

Comment: is `my_module` a directory?

Comment: It is. Actually a package. I just see that I have a typo in the code.

Comment: so is everything ok?

Comment: No. The typo is just from a sample code, in my real project it does not work, even though my module is there and installed.

Comment: is `mymodule` in the same directory as script?

Comment: It is installed via pip in editable mode. As mentioned above, pytest works if run in a normal terminal, but not within vscode.

Comment: well then I likely cannot help you as I use pycharm and have almost no experience with VS Code but have you tried googling?

Answer (score 14):

I played around a little bit with path settings. It finally started to work by using the full path to pytest as workspace setting.

```json
"python.testing.pytestPath": "/home/thomas/.virtualenvs/edis/bin/pytest"
```

Don't ask me why VSCode is not working properly even though pytest is in the path of the virtual environment.

Regards, Thomas

Comment: I've spent so much time trying to figure this out, tried everything. This is the only thing that worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Brilliant!!  wish I had thought of this earlier (and by myself).  Thanks so much....this also resolved an extrmemly annoying issue where my VS Code pylint was flaking out finding some modules.

Comment: The logic describing how VScode finds virtual environments is here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Forcing the path in CMD+Shift+P Select a python interpreter by entering something like /home/thomas/.virtualenvs/edis/bin/python force also Vs Code to use the venv